# Q. javascript. why don't play 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

why don't play onclick="catch()"  ?
I don't understand.

```html
<script>
  function catch () {
    alert("safsf");
  }
</script>
...

<body>
  <td><img src="media/strawberry.png" onclick="catch()"></td>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe that catch() is a reserved function name (for error handling). Use a different function name and it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` is a reserved keyword in javascript. Therefore we can't use it in our function/variable names. Try changing the name of the function:

```js
function error(){
  alert(2);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="error()" class="test">click me 2</div>
```